# Three.js makeOrthographic() units

Tags: matrix, three.js, units-of-measurement, orthographic

I would like to know what the used units are for ( left, right, bottom, top, near, far ) in Three.js Matrix4.makeOrthographic( left, right, bottom, top, near, far ). Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything YOU define them to be. The thing is you don't define them somewhere but you design your world around them. You can say that 10 units corresponds to 10mm or 10cm or 10m or 10km. You design your world around your initial assumption of what a unit is.